# Jackson custom value for nested class's field

Tags: java, jackson

Good day everyone,
Im struggling with serializing object with nested object having custom name with @ JsonProperty.
So, here it is:

```
public class Wrapper {

public final Payload payload;

public Wrapper(String name){
this.payload = new Payload(name);
}    

public static final class Payload{
@JsonProperty("customName")
public final String name;

@JsonCreator
public Payload(@JsonProperty ("customName") String name){

this.name = name;
}
}


}
```

So, in every test I see non-custom name - "name". I added getter with @JsonProperty without any success.

My test class:

```
@JsonTest
public class SerializeWrapperTest {


    @Test
    void whenSerialiseThanCorrect() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Wrapper wrapper =
                new Wrapper("name");
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        Assertions.assertEquals("{"payload":{"customName":"name"}}",json);
    }
}
```

Test results:
Expected :{"payload":{"customName":"name"}}
Actual :{"payload":{"name":"name"}}

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError.

Edited.

Comment: It’s not at all clear what the problem is. Post your json. Post the errors you see.

Comment: Sorry if my info was unclear.

Comment: `@JsonProperty` in a `@JsonCreator` annotated constructor is only used for deserialization. Annotate the field.

Comment: Please see latest edited answer , your junit test case is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood it correct , you need to have a custom property in json for the field , "name".
For that you need to do following -

```
     public class Wrapper {

    public final Payload payload;

    public Wrapper(String name){
        this.payload = new Payload(name);
    }

    public static final class Payload{
        @JsonProperty("customName")
        public final String name;

        public Payload(String name){

            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

**JUnit -**

```
public class WrapperTest {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    public void whenSerialiseThanCorrect() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Wrapper wrapper =
                new Wrapper("Ajeet");
        String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

[image]

```
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ajeet, nope. Actually, Payload is a nested class of Wrapper class. Which field is initializing through Wrapper's constructor. And even when I place @JsonProperty on the field 'name' with custom value, it's still serializing with default value ("name") in my case.

Comment: I read about @JsonTypeInfo(include= JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT) but it's used for polymorphism cases, not nested objects.

Comment: Answer still be the same , As just now , I have written the code and verified. Please check the edited answer with , screen shot .